# Change Svelte Build Homepage

Tags: svelte

I have been building a svelte project, and putting the files in a subdirectory of my apache2 html directory, which would show up online as:

https://websiteName.com/dir/(all the build files are here)

This was done by running
`npm build run` and copying the contents of the project folder to that directory.
The only issue is that the code thinks it is in the
http://websiteName.com/ directory. And so when it goes to call the other build files it gets a 404. So as an example it is trying to grab bundle.js from https://websiteName.com/bundle.js when it actually exists at https://websiteName.com/dir/bundle.js

[image: 404 Errors]

I have tried changing my package.json to reflect this, as the way to fix this in react is adding the homepage property like so:

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "/dir",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  }
 /** **/
}
```

After this change I rebuilt again, and the issue did not seem to be fixed. I could not find if there was a svelte specific keyword for this online so I was wondering if anyone knew what the fix could be.

Comment: Are you using rollup? sveltekit? what does your config look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surmise you're using [Svelte's template for Rollup](https://github.com/sveltejs/template).

Then what I suggest is:

- First, move everything that is in the `public` dir under `public/dir`, so that the `dev` setups continue to works after the other change, with your app in a similar path that your prod setup.
- Change the URLs of the `<script>` and `<link>` tags in (now) `public/dir/index.html` by prepending them with `/dir`:

```html
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/bundle.css" />

    <script defer src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

becomes:

```html
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/bundle.css" />

    <script defer src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

- Finally, change the `output.file` in `rollup.config.js` to build to `public/dir/build` instead of `public/build`:

```js
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    ...
```

becomes:

```js
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/dir/build/bundle.js'
    },
    ...
```

This way you can access your app at `http://localhost:8080/dir/` during dev, and move the content of the `public/dir` to your Apache directory, where the app will keep working under the `/dir` directory.